# wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I know there are quite a few questions on this topic here on SO but none of them seem to be the solution for my case. So, I was hoping someone might be able to help.

When I run a migration I get the following error:

```
CreateEvents: migrating 
-- create_table(:events)
   -> 0.0558s
-- add_index(:events)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

I don't know exactly what I'm looking for and where.  I wanted to change my Users table to a Registrations table.

Registrations Controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
end
```

Registration Model:

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password_digest
end
```

Registration Migration:

```
class CreateRegistrations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :registrations do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130825195829) do

  create_table "activities", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "trackable_id"
    t.string   "trackable_type"
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.string   "owner_type"
    t.string   "key"
    t.text     "parameters"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.string   "recipient_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",     :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     :null => false
  end

  add_index "activities", ["owner_id", "owner_type"], :name =>      "index_activities_on_owner_id_and_owner_type"
  add_index "activities", ["recipient_id", "recipient_type"], :name => "index_activities_on_recipient_id_and_recipient_type"
  add_index "activities", ["trackable_id", "trackable_type"], :name => "index_activities_on_trackable_id_and_trackable_type"

  create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "commenter"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  add_index "comments", ["event_id"], :name => "index_comments_on_event_id"

  create_table "events", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
end
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the create events migration - please paste relevant code here.

Comment: class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :events
  end
end

Comment: `add_index` needs 2 arguments example: `add_index :events, :title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_index` needs 2 arguments example: `add_index :events, :title`